# Spring batch how to transofrm list before writing

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

i'm trying to read a csv file and write data in 2 output csv file.
I am reading lines from csv file rows and i write thoses lines in two csv output files :

But I want to write product grouped by productName in each output files.

A small example to explain

**INPUT FILE**

TOSHIBA    PC    2000

HP         PC    1000

SUMSUNG    TEL   500

Nokia      TEL   300

**OUTPUT FILE tel.csv**

TEL      800  (500 + 300 ) the sum of product which have the same type.

**OUTPUT FILE pc.csv**

PC     3000     ( 2000 + 3000 ) the sum of product which have the same type.

I don't know how to perform that can someone help me ?

Here is my configuration :

```
    <batch:job id="exampleMultiWritersJob">
    <batch:step id="stepMultiWriters">
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="txManager">
            <batch:chunk reader="exampleFileSourceReader" writer="exampleMultiWriters" commit-interval="10">
                <batch:streams>
                    <batch:stream ref="telWriter" />
                    <batch:stream ref="pcWriter" />

                </batch:streams>
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>




<bean id="exampleFileSourceReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" scope="step">
<property name="resource" value="file:#{jobParameters['file']}" />
<property name="lineMapper">
    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
        <!-- split it -->
        <property name="lineTokenizer">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">

                    <!-- this is missing --> 
                    <property name="delimiter" value=";"/>

                    <property name="names" value="name,productType,price" />


            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="fieldSetMapper">
            <!-- map to an object -->
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">

                <property name="prototypeBeanName" value="exampleFileMapper" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</property>
</bean>     


<bean id="exampleFileMapper" class="ma.controle.gestion.modele.Product" scope="prototype"/> 


<!-- This is to demo MultiWriters -->
<bean id="exampleMultiWriters" class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.ClassifierCompositeItemWriter" scope="step">
    <property name="classifier" ref="classifier" />
   </bean>

<bean id="classifier"  class="org.springframework.batch.classify.BackToBackPatternClassifier">
<property name="routerDelegate">
    <bean class="ma.controle.gestion.springbatch.ExampleWriterRouteImpl" />
</property>
<property name="matcherMap">
    <map>
        <entry key="pc" value-ref="pcWriter" />
        <entry key="tel" value-ref="telWriter" />
    </map>
</property>
</bean>

<bean id="pcWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter">
<!-- write to this csv file -->
<property name="resource" value="file:C:/output/pc.csv" />
<property name="shouldDeleteIfExists" value="true" />
<property name="shouldDeleteIfEmpty" value="true" />
<property name="appendAllowed" value="true" />

<property name="lineAggregator">
    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">
        <property name="delimiter" value=";" />
        <property name="fieldExtractor">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
                <property name="names" value="productType,price" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</property>
</bean>



<bean id="telWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter">
<!-- write to this csv file -->
<property name="resource" value="file:C:/output/tel.csv" />
<property name="shouldDeleteIfExists" value="true" />
<property name="shouldDeleteIfEmpty" value="true" />
<property name="appendAllowed" value="true" />

<property name="lineAggregator">
    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">
        <property name="delimiter" value=";" />
        <property name="fieldExtractor">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
                <property name="names" value="productType,price" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</property>
</bean>

    <bean id="itemProcessor" class="ma.controle.gestion.springbatch.BatchItemProcessor" />

<!-- Optional JobExecutionListener to perform business logic before and after the job -->
<bean id="jobListener" class="ma.controle.gestion.springbatch.BatchJobItemListener" />
```

And here is the classifier

```
public class ExampleWriterRouteImpl {

@Classifier
public String classify(Product product){
    if(product.getProductType().equals("TEL"))
        return "tel";
    else if(product.getProductType().equals("PC"))
        return "pc";
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: How big of 2 input CVS files?